# Server Error in Django Web app

Tags: python, django

I'm following this tutorial to fix a cache problem, since I'm using google analytics. After trying the code, I'm getting

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

middleware.py

```
from django.middleware.cache import UpdateCacheMiddleware

import re

class SmartUpdateCacheMiddleware(UpdateCacheMiddleware):
      STRIP_RE=re.compile(r'\b(_[^=]+=.+?(?:; |$))' )

      def process_request(self,request):
          cookie=self.STRIP_RE.sub(",request.META.get('HTTP_COOKIE',")) #error
          request.META['HTTP_COOKIE']=cookie
```

In my cmd terminal I'm getting this error

```
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\env\Scripts\meek\meek\middleware.py", line 9
  cookie=self.STRIP_RE.sub(",request.META.get('HTTP_COOKIE',"))
```

I tried fixing it but it's not working.

Comment: anything more from your stacktrace? can you post a link to the tutorial you're following?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have cut-and-pasted with a typo. It should be:

```
cookie = self.STRIP_RE.sub('', request.META.get('HTTP_COOKIE', ''))
```

You collapsed the double single quotes into a single double quote mark:

```
cookie=self.STRIP_RE.sub(",request.META.get('HTTP_COOKIE',"))
                         ^                                ^
```

Comment: @picomon, could you accept the answer (since it worked)?   Iserni: very well spotted!